# Defining the differentiability of a multivariable function (if/then)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, propositional-calculus, linear-approximation

I'm trying to understand differentiability for multivariable functions and am thoroughly confused by the introduction (and the direction of implications in a certain definition)

I'm given the following definition of differentiability, word-for-word:

> A function f(x,y) is differentiable at (a,b) IF there is a linear function 
>   $$
> L(x,y) = f(a,b) + c(x-a) + d(y-b)  
> $$
>   such that
>   $$
> \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (a,b)} \frac{|f(x,y) - L(x,y)|}{||(x,y) - (a,b)||} = 0
> $$

The presence of the 'if' suggests to me that I can flip the order of the clauses in the sentence, to say:

> "IF this linear function exists (which is characterized as a good approximation of f near the given point), THEN f is differentiable."

But this isn't an if-and-only-if, so the converse isn't necessarily true. i.e. f being differentiable doesn't mean that this linear function exists.

Then most resources I see follow up with a theorem

> If f is differentiable at (a,b), then the linear function 
>   $$
> L(x,y) = f(a,b) + c(x-a) + d(y-b)  
> $$
>    is identical to the linear approximation, where c = f_x (a,b) and d=f_y (a,b).

The proof of this is where I get confused, because the first step in all the resources I've seen start with

> Since f is differentiable at (a,b), we have 
>   $$
> \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (a,b)} \frac{|f(x,y) - L(x,y)|}{||(x,y) - (a,b)||} = 0
> $$

But I thought this was the hypothesis of the definition, not the conclusion! The function is differentiable if such a linearization exists. Rephrased, "If such a linearization exists, the function is differentiable." This proof is using the converse by saying that if it's differentiable, the linear function with error->0 exists.

Am I misinterpreting the implication in the definition? I've seen the exact same wording in multiple definitions online. "f is differentiable IF", not "if f is differentiable THEN". My head hurts. Please save me from my misery.

Comment: A function $f(x,y)$ is differentiable at $(a,b)$ is a definition so you get the reverse implication for free since it is not true or false on its own.

Comment: The existence of the Linear map is a necessary and sufficient requirement, this being a definition after all. Definitions do not have hypothesis and conclusions. It is just phrased that way by the looks of it. Though I can mention a number of books where it is explicitly stated as if and only if.

Comment: It's a definition, so really it's "if and only if". Anyway, think of it that way "$f$ is differentiable at $(a,b)$" is a new predicate, shorthand for the more elaborate formula "$... f.... (a,b)... $". That formula is not a *hypothesis*, it's a definition. There's no wider meaning of "differentiable" except as stated.